# Should I always use `T&&` instead of `const T&` or `T&` to bind to a callback function?

Tags: c++

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(..., T && callback) {
    ...
    callback(...);
    ...
}
```

Is it preferable to use `T &&` than `T&` or `const T&`?

Or even simply `T` to pass by value instead of pass by reference.

Does function or lambdas have the concept of lvalue & rvalue? Can I `std::move` a function / lambdas?

Does `const` of `const T&` enforce that the function cannot modify its closure?

Comment: If you look at all standard library functions using predicates or callbacks (like e.g. [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)) then you will see that it's passed by value.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  Updated question. I hate so many choices....

Answer (score 5):

Taking a forwarding reference can make a difference, but you have to call the callback correctly to see it.  for functions and lambdas it doesn't matter if they are an rvalue or lvalue, but if you have a functor, it can make a difference

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(..., T && callback) {
    callback(...);
}
```

Takes a forwarding reference, and then calls the callback as a lvalue.  This can be an error if the function object was passed as an rvalue, and its call operator is defined as

```
operator()(...) && { ... }
```

since that is only callable on an rvalue.  To make your function work correctly you need to wrap the function name in `std::forward` so you call it in the same value expression category it was passed to the function as.  That looks like

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(..., T && callback) {
    std::forward<T>(callback)(...); 
    // you should only call this once since callback could move some state into its return value making UB to call it again
}
```

So, if you want to take rvalues and lvalues, and call the operator as an rvalue or lvalue, then the above approach should be used, since it is just like doing the call in the call site of `myFunction`.

Comment: Might want to note the usual caveat of "only `std::forward` an argument once"

Comment: @Caleth In this it makes no difference since it isn't assigned or initialized to anything.  `forward` doesn't move anything, it just makes it moveable.  `std::forward<T>(callback)(...); more stuff; std::forward<T>(callback)(...);` is perfectly legal to do.

Comment: It's legal, but if you have an `operator()(...) &&` it probably moves something out of the callable into the result

Comment: @Caleth Ah yes.  Forgot about that.  Noted

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to choose either `T` (with optional `std::ref`) or `T&&` and stick with one or the other.

`T const&` works if you want to let the caller know that `myFunction` won't modify `callback`.  It doesn't work if `callback` might be stateful.  Of course, if `callback`'s `operator()` is marked `const` (or `callback` is a non-`mutable` lambda), then `myFunction` won't modify `callback`.  Essentially, whoever calls `myFunction` can provide that constness guarantee for themselves.

`T&` works if you want `myFunction` to be allowed to take in a stateful functor.  The drawback is that `T&` can't bind to an rvalue (e.g. `myFunction([&](Type arg){ /* whatever */ })`).

`T` is good for both stateful and stateless functors, and it works for both rvalues (e.g. lambdas) and lvalues.  If somebody who calls `myFunction` wants changes to `callback`'s state to be observable outside of `myFunction` (e.g. `callback` has more than just `operator()`), they can use `std::ref`.  This is what the C++ standard library seems to go with.

`T&&` is similarly general-purpose (it can handle rvalues and/or stateful functors), but it doesn't require `std::ref` to make changes to `callback` be visible from outside of `myFunction`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it preferable to use T && than T& or const T&?

Universal references allow perfect forwarding, so they are often preferable in generic template functions.

> Or even simply T to pass by value instead of pass by reference.

This is often preferable when you wish to take ownership.

> Does function or lambdas have the concept of lvalue & rvalue?

Yes. Every value expression has a value category.

> Can I std::move a function / lambdas?

Yes. You can `std::move` pretty much anything.

Another matter is whether `std::move`'d object is moved from. And yet another matter is whether an object can be moved. Lambdas are movable unless they contain non-movable captures.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's example:

```
template <typename T>
void myFunction(..., T && callback) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Passing a `T&&` will give you the best of both worlds. If we pass an r-value reference, the template resolves the function with an r-value reference, but if we pass an l-value reference, the function resolves as a l-value. When passing `callback` just remember to use `std::forward` to preserve the l/r value.

This only works if T is templated, this is not the case where we use something like a std::function.

So what do we pass in the non-templated example. The first thing to decide is whether `callback` can be called after the exit of the function. In the event that the callback will only be called during the scope of `myFunc`, you are probably better off using l-value references, since you can call the reference directly.

However if `callback` will be called after the scope of `myFunc`, using an r-value will allow you to `move` `callback`. This will save you the copy but forces you to guarantee that callback cannot be used anywhere else after passing to `myFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ functions (not to be confused with `std::function`) are essentially just pointers. You can move pointers, though it's the same as copying them.

Lambdas under the hood are just more or less regular `struct`s (or `class`es, it's the same) that implement `operator()` and potentially store some state (if your lambda captures it). So the `move` would function just the same as it would for regular structs.

Similarly, there could be `move-only` lambdas (because they have move-only values in their state). So sometimes, if you want to accept such lambdas, you need to pass by `&&`.

However, in some cases you want a copy (for example if you want to execute function in a thread).

Comment: You can take a move only lambda by lvalue reference.

Comment: @NathanOliver you can, but doesn't mean you should. It's not always safe to modify a functor's state if you don't own it.